# how to read curl on remote server and reply

Tags: php, curl

I want to send some data to remote server and wait for its reply, 
i'm using curl to post data.

This is my client code:

```
 $arr = array ('id' => $company , 'imei' => $drivers ,'startDate' => $startDate ,'endDate' => $endDate, 'token' => $token);
$string = http_build_query($arr);

$ch = curl_init("http://127.0.0.1/Codiad/workspace/PFE/S/server.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST , true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS , $string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

The server should read `$string`, and do some checks based on received `id`, `imei` ...
and reply to client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is what worked for me

1- sender.php:

```
function curlPost($url, $data) {
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $result;
} 
print(curlPost("http://127.0.0.1/receiver.php", array("message"=>"Hello World")));
```

2- receiver.php:

```
print("received ".$_REQUEST['message']);
```

or

```
print("received ".$_POST['message']);
```